# Initalizing 0 UTC Time generates a negative time when printed

Tags: datetime, go

In the provided code snippet the `t2` time initialized explicitly to 0 UTC is negative when printed.

I don't understand why that is, could someone explain it for me?

```
func main() {
    const IsoDatetimeFormat = "2006-01-02T15:04:05"
    t1 := time.Time{}
    t2 := time.Date(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
    fmt.Println(t1.Format(IsoDatetimeFormat))
    fmt.Println(t2.Format(IsoDatetimeFormat))
}
```

Output:

0001-01-01T00:00:00

-0001-11-30T00:00:00

[playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/AZGdfMbUINL)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks about facts that are clearly documented in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

[`time.Time`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time) documents that the zero value for `time.Time` represents / means January 1, year 1, 00:00:00.000000000 UTC:

> The zero value of type Time is January 1, year 1, 00:00:00.000000000 UTC. As this time is unlikely to come up in practice, the IsZero method gives a simple way of detecting a time that has not been initialized explicitly.

[There is no year 0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_zero), so if you use year, month and day values smaller than 1, they will roll over to negative. The `time` package accepts and normalizes values given outside of valid ranges. Quoting from [`time.Date()`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Date):

> The month, day, hour, min, sec, and nsec values may be outside their usual ranges and will be normalized during the conversion. For example, October 32 converts to November 1.

The zero value to be January 1, year 1 was an arbitrary choice. As to reasoning *why* year 1 was chosen:

```
// The zero value for a Time is defined to be
//  January 1, year 1, 00:00:00.000000000 UTC
// which (1) looks like a zero, or as close as you can get in a date
// (1-1-1 00:00:00 UTC), (2) is unlikely enough to arise in practice to
// be a suitable "not set" sentinel, unlike Jan 1 1970, and (3) has a
// non-negative year even in time zones west of UTC, unlike 1-1-0
// 00:00:00 UTC, which would be 12-31-(-1) 19:00:00 in New York.
```

Comment: What do you mean there is no year 0? Isn't year 0 simply the year before year 1? and negative years would be BC

Comment: The year before 1 AD is 1 BC. See [Wikipedia: Year zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_zero).

Comment: Interesting, makes me wonder why it doesn't return an error on year 0 in

Comment: @Bomaz Month 0 and Day 0 should be stranger than year 0. As wrote in the answer, the `time` package accepts and normalizes values given outside of valid ranges. If you try to create a time providing January 32, 2021, you will get February 1, 2021. This is documented at `time.Date()`. Edited the answer to make that clear.